# Log4j Properties File for Monthly Backup

Tags: log4j

What is the required configuration in `log4j.properties` file in order to backup log file in the end of each month (monthly rolling) and continue to have the same name for active log file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found that `DatePattern` does the trick:

```
log4j.appender.applog=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.applog.encoding=UTF-8
log4j.appender.applog.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.applog.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss} %m%n
log4j.appender.applog.File=log/process.log
log4j.appender.applog.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM
```

Here, name of the active log file is always "process.log" and at the beginning of each month the file is saved with the name "process.log.yyyy-MM" when the first log of that month is pushed to log4j and the active log file is reset.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the DailyRollingFileAppender and the date pattern configuration. Refer to http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html
and 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm

Comment: Of course I looked at these pages. But it is not clear how to keep name of the active log file constant and rename only for backups and i didn't want to play with system time to test effect of different parameters. I thought somebody can provide an already tested config. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you could test it with a minute roll over. the beavior of the renaming should be the same by the monthly configuration.